# Python 3: why the result of input() in ['y', 'Y'] is false when I enter y?

Tags: windows-7, input, python-3.2

I am very new to Python.  And I wrote the following script in a file:

```
# ...\temp\test.py
x = (input() in ['y', 'Y'])
print(x)
```

And run it in the command line:

```
python test.py

y

False
```

As my understanding, the printed result should be True.  But the actual result is False.  Why is this?

my environment:
OS: win7
Python: 3.2

Answer (score 0):

It works fine for me in Ubuntu. The only thing I can think of is Windows sticking on extra blank space. Try this:

```
x = (input().strip() in ['y', 'Y'])
```

If that doesn't work then do this:

```
y = input()
x = (y in ['y', 'Y'])
print(y)
print(x)
```

Then you will be able to see what is in fact returned by input()

Comment: it works on Win7 with script "x = (input().strip() in ['y', 'Y'])".  And it works fine with all of the scripts includes both of yours and mine on XP.  Seems it is the OS environment related issue.  Thanks so much for your response.

Comment: @KurtisZhao: did you check what is actually stored in 'y' in the second piece of code there? Can you please say what it is?

Comment: I searched several days on the internet and tried hours on my win7 machine, but still cannot get the answer.  I will go on investigating it, and will let you know when get it (hope I can get it).  If you get the answer, please share it with me.  Thanks.

Comment: it is a bug on 3.2 and has been fixed on 3.3.  Today, I re-installed 3.3 on my win7 machine and it works now.  Thanks for your help.